# btrfs quotas: Can't delete files when quota is exceeded

Tags: windows, smb, btrfs, quota

I set quotas on our smb server's `/home/<name>` subvolumes.

These subvolumes are exposed over smb as `\\server\<name>`

Now whenever someone tries to delete files in his/her /home folder and is above quota,
they can't delete anything.

On Windows, the files seem deleted until they do a refresh (eg. exiting and re-entering the directory or pressing F5).
On Linux the error is somewhat more visible: `rm: cannot remove 'file': Disk quota exceeded`

Is this error by design or is there a workaround?

The users of course don't have ssh access to the server, so I need a solution that works on Windows. (No `echo -n > file` or `cat /dev/null > file` possible)

Comment: The [wiki says](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#..._files_cannot_be_deleted_once_the_filesystem_is_full) that _"many of these bugs have been fixed, and current evidence (May 2015) suggests that if there are remaining bugs in this area, they are very, very hard to hit"_, so you must have tried very, very hard ;)

Comment: I found my error: Debian stretch (which I have to use for reasons) only has btrfs-progs 4.20, which is OLD

Comment: @gronostaj Can you make an answer out of that? Else I would do it. Just want to be able to mark this as officially solved.

Comment: I don't think I deserve reputation for this one :) You've found the culprit: old btrfs-progs. That would be a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my distribution shipping btrfs-progs from ages ago, so many bugs were not yet fixed.